# How to access textbox inside grid view of parent page in popup page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I have a pop up page where I want to get the textbox value which is inside gridview of main page,
and populate value in that textbox.

I have tried:

```
  var Emp = window.opener.document.getElementById('grd_txtEmp');
  Emp.rows[1].cells[3].childNodes[0].value="abc";
```

My popup page:

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="#C0C0C0" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="Black" HeaderText="Man">
      <ItemTemplate>     
      <table><tr><td>                                       
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpy" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"  ontextchanged="txtEmploy_TextChanged" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# Eval("Empry") %>'  Width="98%"></asp:TextBox>
       </td>
       <td align="right">
       <a href="javascript:window.open('Select.aspx', 'mywindow', 'menubar=1,resizable=1,width=600,height=400, top=200, left=400');">Select</a>   

      </td></tr></table>
      </ItemTemplate>
      
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Silver" BorderColor="Black"  Width="30%"/>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Is this the only textbox in the row?  Do you perform the popup upon clicking the box?  You could try to get and save the row index when the click happens and then write to the box afte the return.
     GridView.rows[rowIdx].cells[col].value = <value returned>

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you are opening the popup, on clicking of some link or button  in the grid view row. If this is correct, then while opening the popup, you can pass the textbox id to the popup as a query string. Then you can set the value to the correct text box from the poped up window. To get the id of the textbox in the current row, you can use jQuery

As an example, you can try this idea
Add a css class to the textbox, say, "extdata"
Add a css class to the link/button, say, "popupopener"
Then add the following jQuery

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.popupopener').each(function () {
            $(this).click(function () {
                //If the textbox is at the same level as the link button
                var textBoxId = $(this).closest("table").find('.extdata').attr('id');
                window.open("Select.aspx" + "?textboxid=" + textBoxId, "mywindow", 'menubar=1,resizable=1,width=600,height=400, top=200, left=400');
            }
        );
        });
    });
```

Change the layout as below

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="#C0C0C0" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="Black" HeaderText="Man">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpy" CssClass="extdata" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" OnTextChanged="txtEmploy_TextChanged" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# Eval("Empry") %>' Width="98%"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td align="right">
                                <a class="popupopener">Select</a>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>

                <HeaderStyle BackColor="Silver" BorderColor="Black" Width="30%" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: yes but how to pass the textbox id to the popup as a query string.@Kiran hegde

Comment: I have added example above

Comment: See my edited code.As I am popuplating the pop up page through design page.@Kiran hegde

Comment: Try the changes as I made above

Comment: Thanks.But I am unable to even open the pop up page as there is no link available.@Kiran Hegde

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55717/discussion-between-kiran-hegde-and-sona).